# Javascript - getting the element offset value on scroll not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the top offset element value on scroll and calculate so that I can change the classes for the elements if I have reached the element on scroll. This is the function:

```
handleScroll () {
    const header = document.querySelector('#header');
    const content = document.querySelector('#content');
    const rect = header.getBoundingClientRect();
    const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    const headerTop = rect.top + scrollTop;
    console.log(headerTop);
    if (window.scrollY > headerTop) {
      header.classList.add('fixed');
      content.classList.add('content-margin');
    } else {
      header.classList.remove('fixed');
      content.classList.remove('content-margin');
    }
  }
},
beforeMount () {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
},
beforeDestroy () {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
}
```

But, on checking the `console.log(headerTop);`. on scroll, I see that I keep getting the different values for headerTop while I am scrolling, only when I stop scrolling I get the correct value. How can I fix that, to get the correct value on scroll?

Comment: try to produce a working code

Answer (score 0):

The `getBoundingClientRect()` function will return a box relative to the current window position. When the element is sticky, it's top value will always be 0, or something else fixed.

This can for instance be solved by adding an empty div before the sticky element, and use that as a reference point of offsets.